# Laravel reverb with ssl on nginx

Tags: laravel, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, laravel-10, laravel-websockets

Currently changing beyondcode/laravel-websockets for laravel/reverb

Reverb and laravel echo success running on local without ssl

I use a simple chirper laravel app:
https://github.com/jbarreraballestas/laravel-chirper-react-realtime/tree/laravel-reverb

`config/reverb.php`

```php
'servers' => [

        'reverb' => [
            'host' => env('REVERB_SERVER_HOST', '0.0.0.0'),
            'port' => env('REVERB_SERVER_PORT', 8080),
            'hostname' => env('REVERB_HOST'),
            'options' => [
                'tls' => [
                        'local_cert'=>'/chirper_cert/cert1.pem' // certbot certificate with 777 permissions while check if success but not work
                ],
            ],
            'scaling' => [
                'enabled' => env('REVERB_SCALING_ENABLED', false),
                'channel' => env('REVERB_SCALING_CHANNEL', 'reverb'),
            ],
            'pulse_ingest_interval' => env('REVERB_PULSE_INGEST_INTERVAL', 15),
        ],

    ],
```

Trying to use proxy pass

```
server {

        root /var/www/laravel-chirper-react-realtime/public;
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";
        index index.php;
        charset utf-8;
        server_name example.com;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        }

        location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
        location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
        error_page 404 /index.php;

        location ~ \.php$ {
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.3-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }
# Added this for Web Sockets Proxy
    location /ws/ {
     proxy_pass             http://127.0.0.1:8080;
     proxy_set_header Host  $host;
     proxy_read_timeout     60;
     proxy_connect_timeout  60;
     proxy_redirect         off;

    # Allow the use of websockets
     proxy_http_version 1.1;
     proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
     proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
     proxy_set_header Host $host;
     proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    listen [::]:443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
```

Error:

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss://example:8080/app/fl2qodkdxamxyygnpbur?protocol=7&client=js&version=8.4.0-rc2&flash=false' failed
```

Comment: `listen 443 ssl` doesn't seem to line up with `wss://example:8080`

Answer (score 0):

I made a new subdomain for example

```
server {
    server_name wss.yourdomain.net www.wss.yourdomain.net;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/wss_access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/wss_error.log;
    root /var/www/yourdomain.net/public;

    index index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header Scheme $scheme;
        proxy_set_header SERVER_PORT $server_port;
        proxy_set_header REMOTE_ADDR $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";

        proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:8080;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.2-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css)$ {
        expires 365d;
    }

    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/wss.yourdomain.net/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/wss.yourdomain.net/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
```

then modified .env on **root** domain updating the **reverb** hostname and commented out the **reverb** port. Inside reverb config I've also put
`'port' => env('REVERB_PORT', null)`

- `php artisan reverb:restart`
- `php artisan reverb:start --debug`

test your URL `wss://wss.yourdomain.net/app/{REVERB_APP_KEY}?protocol=7&client=js&version=8.4.0-rc2&flash=false @ https://websocketking.com/`

Answer (score -2):

***Install laravel/reverb in laravel 10***

```bash
composer require laravel/reverb:dev-main
```

```bash
php artisan reverb:install
```

***Install laravel/reverb in laravel 11***

```bash
php artisan install:broadcasting
```

**nginx listen on 443:**

```
server{
...
location /app {
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header Scheme $scheme;
    proxy_set_header SERVER_PORT $server_port;
    proxy_set_header REMOTE_ADDR $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
    proxy_read_timeout 300s;
    proxy_connect_timeout 75s;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
}
...
}
```

**Update laravel .env**

```
REVERB_HOST="example.com"
REVERB_PORT=443
REVERB_SCHEME=https
```

**Build resources**

```bash
npm run build
```

Now connection to websockets will be established through secure connections

**Related resources links:**

https://serverfault.com/questions/1156283/how-to-successfull-configure-nginx-for-laravel-reverb-websocket

https://youtu.be/LiinzmPRYHE (spanish)